# I need to Un-nest JSON array elements AND ensure correct mapping with 'ID' column

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

The input DataFrame "df" which is as follows (Please take note of values in 'id' column):

```
| id    | name                                                                                  |
|-------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| a1xy  | [  {  "event": "sports",   "start": "100"},  {  "event": "lunch",  "start": "121" } ] |
| a7yz  | [  {  "event": "lunch",   "start": "109"},  {  "event": "movie",  "start": "97" } ]   |
| bx4y  | [  {  "event": "dinner",   "start": "78"},  {  "event": "sleep",  "start": "25" } ]   |
```

I want to flatten the JSON array elements so that my result output is:

```
| id    | name.event | name.start |
|-------|------------|------------|
| a1xy  | sports     | 100        |
| a1xy  | lunch      | 121        |
| a7yz  | lunch      | 109        |
| a7yz  | movie      | 97         |
| bx4y  | dinner     | 78         |
| bx4y  | sleep      | 25         |
```

The values in the 'id' column need to be mapped correctly. How can I do this in Python?

I tried:

```
k = df.name.map(json.loads).apply(pd.DataFrame).tolist()
final_df = pd.concat(k)
```

But I am unable to map the values in the 'id' column.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: Input is `json` ? Is possible use `json_normalize` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with flattening and update each dictionary by `id` values, last call `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].map(json.loads)

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(y, id=i) for i, x in zip(df['id'],df['name']) for y in x])
print (df)
    event    id start
0  sports  a1xy   100
1   lunch  a1xy   121
2   lunch  a7yz   109
3   movie  a7yz    97
4  dinner  bx4y    78
5   sleep  bx4y    25
```

But if input is `json`, better is use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

**Timings**:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
['a1xy',[{  "event": "sports",   "start": "100"}, {  "event": "lunch",  "start": "121" } ]],
['a7yz',[{  "event": "lunch",   "start": "109"},  {  "event": "movie",  "start": "97" }  ]],
['bx4y',[{  "event": "dinner",   "start": "78"},  {  "event": "sleep",  "start": "25" }  ]]],
columns=['id','name']) 
print (df)

#3k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [276]: %%timeit
     ...: pd.DataFrame([dict(y, id=i) for i, x in zip(df['id'],df['name']) for y in x])
9.49 ms ± 230 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [277]: %%timeit
     ...: finalArray=[]
     ...: df.apply(lambda x: addtoArray(x,finalArray),axis=1)
     ...: pd.DataFrame(finalArray,columns=['col1','event','start'])
     ...: 
1.81 s ± 33.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

List comprehension solution is `180x` faster.

Comment: how do I 'programmatically'  add elements of the 'id' column into the 'name' column? I want to use json_normalize

Comment: @Symphony - How looks `json` ?

Comment: @Symphony - It is like `[{'id': 'a1xy', 'name': [{'event': 'sports', 'start': '100'},{'event': 'lunch', 'start': '121'}]},
        {'id': 'a7yz', 'name': [{'event':'lunch', 'start': '109'},'event': 'movie', 'start': '97'}]},
        {'id': 'bx4y', 'name': [{'event': 'dinner', 'start': '78'},{'event': 'sleep', 'start': '25'}]}]` ?

Comment: [  {  "event": "sports",   "start": "100"},  {  "event": "lunch",  "start": "121" } ]

Comment: [  { "id": "a1xy", "event": "sports",   "start": "100"},  { "id": "a1xy", "event": "lunch",  "start": "121" } ]

Comment: @Symphony - Not sure if understand, because `json_normalize` is used if your input data are json file or json string. So I ask how looks your data. If input data is DataFrame like in your question, use `json_normalize` is worse solution as my answer. And if check `[dict(y, id=i) for i, x in zip(df['id'],df['name']) for y in x]` it exactly add `id` to `dict` and also flatten nested lists to one big `list of dictionaries`.

Comment: ok got it. my input dataframe is exactly like in the question. So, how do I convert my input dataframe into :

Comment: [{'id': 'a1xy', 'name': [{'event': 'sports', 'start': '100'},{'event': 'lunch', 'start': '121'}]}, {'id': 'a7yz', 'name': [{'event':'lunch', 'start': '109'},'event': 'movie', 'start': '97'}]}, {'id': 'bx4y', 'name': [{'event': 'dinner', 'start': '78'},{'event': 'sleep', 'start': '25'}]}]

Comment: @Symphony - use `d = df.to_dict('r')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external function within the apply function as well

```
import json
data=pd.DataFrame([
['a1xy',[{  "event": "sports",   "start": "100"}, {  "event": "lunch",  "start": "121" } ]],
['a7yz',[{  "event": "lunch",   "start": "109"},  {  "event": "movie",  "start": "97" }  ]],
['bx4y',[{  "event": "dinner",   "start": "78"},  {  "event": "sleep",  "start": "25" }  ]]],columns=['id','name']) 

def addtoArray(x,finalArray):
    finalArray.extend(np.insert(pd.DataFrame(x['name']).values,0,x['id'],axis=1).tolist())

finalArray=[]
data.apply(lambda x: addtoArray(x,finalArray),axis=1)
finalArray=pd.DataFrame(finalArray,columns=['col1','event','start'])
print(finalArray)

   col1   event start
0  a1xy  sports   100
1  a1xy   lunch   121
2  a7yz   lunch   109
3  a7yz   movie    97
4  bx4y  dinner    78
5  bx4y   sleep    25
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have list of json objects as the following input

```
data = [{'id': 'a1xy', 'name': [{'event': 'sports', 'start': '100'},{'event': 'lunch', 'start': '121'}]},
        {'id': 'a7yz', 'name': [{'event':'lunch', 'start': '109'},'event': 'movie', 'start': '97'}]},
        {'id': 'bx4y', 'name': [{'event': 'dinner', 'start': '78'},{'event': 'sleep', 'start': '25'}]}]

df = json_normalize(data, record_path='name', meta='id', record_prefix='name.')
print(df)
```